# Amazon S3 vs Cloudfront for hosting mp3 and images?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm building an application for an artist and suggested that they host the mp3 files on s3 as its free up to a certain bandwidth for the first year.

The app will stream several record albums of 160kbit mp3 files on s3, along with some 1280 x 720.jpg images which the application downloads on launch.

The app needs to get these images (about 250 k each) as fast as possible, and is not able to cache them locally after it is terminated, each time it is launched it will re-download the images.

Given an expectation of 10k to 100k users, possibly more, mostly in the USA, would adding Cloudfront to the picture be of value, and is it more likely to bankrupt someone who doesn't have a high income than just using S3 alone?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Amazon Web Services [Simple Monthly Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html).

You can enter your assumptions about storage and data transfer into it and see the expected costs. You clearly already know that CloudFront will have dramatically lower latency for your clients.

I'm making a basic assumption of 1 hour of daily streaming per user, and your range of 10k to 100k users.

[This source](http://www.audiomountain.com/tech/audio-file-size.html) gives 160kbit mp3 audio as 72 MB/hour, so we will use the formula below to calculate total monthly transfers:

```
72 MB/hour * 1 hour/user/day * 30 day/month * 10k user
```

This gives:

1. **20 terabytes / month for 10k users**
2. **200 terabytes / month for 100k users**

Using the above numbers, here's your costs:

- **S3-only is between $2,000 and $16,000 per month**
- **CloudFront adds between $2,000 and $13,000 per month on top of that**

---

TL;DR **In your scenario, using CloudFront roughly doubles the cost** - regardless of the number of users.

You should also consider that the actual cost might be lower if you contact Amazon to buy reserved capacity on CloudFront in exchange for a better rate for transfer costs. From their [CloudFront pricing page](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/):

> Reserved Capacity gives you the option to commit to a minimum monthly usage level for 12 months or longer and in turn receive a significant discount. Reserved Capacity agreements begin at a minimum of 10 TB of data transfer per month from a single region. Customers who commit to higher usage receive additional discounts.

Apparently [in some cases](http://blog.streamingmedia.com/the_business_of_online_vi/2011/08/amazon-lowers-cloudfront-cdn-pricing-estimate-cdn-business-brings-in-75m.html) the difference of having reserved capacity might save you as much as 50% of CloudFront costs, which would mean **CloudFront would only account for about 1/3rd of your total transfer costs instead of half**.

Answer (score 1):

S3 is meant for static data only like images and using cloudfront will be of great help.